# how to solve a Partial Differential equations numerically of the kind given below

Tags: differential-equations, mathematica-online

```
eq=D[f[x,y],y]+ f[x,y]/y == Q[x,y]
```

The equation doesn't have any derivative with respect to x. If I use the following syntax for [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) will it give me the correct result?

```
NDSolve[{eq, boundary condition},{x,x_min,x_max},{y,y_min,y_max}]
```

Comment: Have you defined the value of $Q$? NDSolve is a numerical solver so everything must reduce to a numerical value for it to work. Also, have you tried to run your syntax and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I have defined Q numerically. My syntax is working but the answer I am getting from it is not the one I am looking for. I want to know if this syntax works properly for my differential equation.

Comment: Prantik, you should include the definition of $Q$, the results you get from the NDSolve, and your reason why those results do not make sense to you. It’s hard to help further otherwise.

Comment: The form of Q  is "y x^-2" kind. The exact expression is difficult to write here.

Answer (score 1):

Some insight can be obtained by solving this differential equation symbolically.

```
DSolveValue[eq, f[x, y], {x, y}]
(* C[1][x]/y + Inactive[Integrate][K[1]*Q[x, K[1]], {K[1], 1, y}]/y *)
```

If `Q[x,y]` is given by `y/x^2`, the solution reduces to

```
(* y^2/(3*x^2) + C[1][x]/y *)
```

And, to answer the question explicitly posed, the code in the question should yield the correct answer, barring numerical instabilities and the like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help